# Analysis of Algorithms Observation

Tags: analysis

a.Use induction to prove that $T(n) = \theta(n^k \lg n)$

b.The preceding fact shows that we could, in principle, extend Case $2$ of the Master Theorem to
include more overhead functions than simply those that have order of growth $\theta(nE)$, where
$E$ is the critical exponent. State a revised version of Case 2 of the Master Theorem to reflect
this extension.

c.Use this extended definition of the Master Theorem to find a closed form solution for $T(n)$
that is defined by $T(n) = 1$ for $n=1$ and for $n > 1$: $T(n) = 9T(n/3) + 2n \lg n$

Comment: ... and your efforts are... ?

Comment: Please make sure the the question has been edited properly.

Comment: What is $T(n)$?    What is n^^k?  We use one caret for powers, but I don't understand two.  Please format your question using $\LaTeX$.  A guide is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  In particular, there are two strange symbols, one after theta in the first line and one between n and 1 in the last.

Comment: Thanks for the edit pondy i have been having some trouble trying to answer these questions

Comment: And the 'Master Theorem' is...

Comment: Part (a) is going to be difficult as it now stands. Perhaps if you gave the preamble to this set of questions....

Answer (score 0):

I can perhaps be of help here in finding the closed form solution by first solving the related recurrence
$$ S(n) = 9 S(\lfloor n/3\rfloor) + 2 n (\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor + 1) $$
where $S(0) = 0$ and the logarithmic term is adapted to make the calculation easier without changing the asymptotics.

Let the base three representation of $n$ be
$$ n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} d_k 3^k.$$

Then it is not difficult to see that
$$ S(n) = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}  (\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor +1-j) 9^j
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} d_k 3^{k-j} =
2  \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}  (\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor+1-j) 3^j
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} d_k 3^k.$$ 
This formula is exact.

Now to get an upper bound on this consider the case where all digits of $n$ are equal to two. This yields
$$ S(n)\le  4  \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}  (\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor+1-j) 3^j
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} 3^k \\
= \frac{351}{32} 9^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}
- 3 \lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor 3^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}
- \frac{15}{2} 3^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} +
\frac{1}{4} \lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor + \frac{17}{32}.$$

For a lower bound take the case of $n$ consisting of a leading one digit followed by zeros, giving
$$ S(n)\ge 2  \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}  (\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor+1-j) 3^j
3^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} \\
= 2 \times 3^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}  (\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor+1-j) 3^j =
\frac{9}{2} 9^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} 
- \lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor 3^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}
- \frac{5}{2} 3^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} .$$
These two bounds are actually attained and cannot be improved.

To conclude we still need to correct for the fact that $T(1) = 1$ whereas $S(1) = 2.$
This is particularly straightforward, we have
$$ T(n) = S(n) - [[d_{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor} = 1]] 9^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}.$$

Putting it all together we have shown that
$$ T(n)\in\Theta\left(9^{\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}\right) =
\Theta\left(3^{2\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor}\right)= \Theta(n^2).$$
This holds even when the recurrence includes a logarithm to a base other than three (scaled by a constant factor) or a different choice of approximation of that logarithm ($1+\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor$ is within a distance of one of the exact value, just like $\lfloor\log_3 n\rfloor$). The next term in the asymptotics is $n\log n.$

Comment: Can part a) be proven though i have consulted alot of textbooks and i am confused